# Shorcut to show all Finder windows

Tags: keyboard, finder

Wondering if there's a shortcut available to show all open Finder windows? Not sure what to call this behaviour; not 'focus all windows', since that involves a single window, not 'raise all window', since that also involves a single window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a shortcut but there is a menu item: Window / Bring All to Front. You can use System Preferences / Keyboard / Keyboard Shortcuts to add one.

Answer (score 1):

I found that there's two additional methods one can use:

- while a Finder window has focus, ⌘-tab to another application, then ⌘-tab back to Finder
- click the Finder icon in the Dock.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the **Finder Menu** item "Hide Others": command-option-H.
That'll hide everything except Finder Windows, which'll make all open Finder windows visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can press Control + Down (^ + ↓)